# UIBezierPath containsPoint: don't work correctly?(Updated: touch location in superview how to handle?)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibezierpath

So I have 2 UIViews witch can draw a bezierpath and then returns the path. Then I need to check if the path contains a point I do this with help of `[path containsPoint:currentObject.position]`and it works for one of the views but not the other.
One view is on the top half of the iPhone and the other view is on the bottom half. The one on the bottom don't work. 
I tried to switch the views, and then it was the same problem, the bottom one doesn't work.

Here is some code:

in mainviewcontroller:

```
-(void)didEndPath:(UIBezierPath *)path DrawView:(DrawView *)draw {
    if ([path containsPoint:currentObject.position]) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

and in drawview touches ended I do this:

```
[self.delegate didEndPath:currentPath DrawView:self];
```

Why doesn't it work, can it be that the view has another origin then self.view? How do I fix it?

EDIT:

Okey, so I found the problem but not the solution.

If I change the touch methods in my UIView from this:
`startPoint = [touch locationInView:self];`to this `startPoint = [touch locationInView:self.superview];`then it reads the touches correctly but my path won't draw. Still the problem is only with the bottom uiview. So how can I change so it returns a path with touches location in superview, but draws it within it self?

Comment: What is contained in the BezierPAth: Has the path some self intersection?

Comment: @AlexWien Just a closed path with no self intersection.

Comment: Is `currentObject.position` in the same coordinate system as the bezierPaths? I use `containsPoint:` constantly without incident.

Comment: @rsswtmr Actually I found now that that is the problem, but do you know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by making 2 paths. One with points from superview and one without. It works but i don't know if its the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation:

```
A point is not considered to be enclosed by the path if it is inside an open subpath,   
regardless of whether that area would be painted during a fill operation. Therefore, to
determine mouse hits on open paths, you must create a copy of the path object and  
explicitly close any subpaths (using the closePath method) before calling this method.
```

My guess is that you left a subpath opened, so containsPoint returns NO.

Comment: No, It is closed. But I have found where the problem starts now, I've updated the question.

Comment: Make sure that you do the drawing in the drawRect method.

Comment: I do, but now the problem is that if I create the path with points from superView, then the containsPoint method works. But the path will not draw itself in the right place, but if I do the opposite the containsPoint method will not work, but the path will draw correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just convert the points between the views like this

```
CGPoint locationInSuperView = [self convertPoint:point toView:self.superview];
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert a whole path at once?

Comment: Yes and No. It would be easier to build two paths side by side. If you want to do it after the fact you could take a look at building the second path using `CGPathApply`

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought, well then I stick with my solution by creating to paths side by side.

Comment: Out of interest why do you need to actually build two paths? Can you not have the one path and then convert the points using the above method before checking if they are in that path?

Comment: I need one path to draw in its own view (in drawRect). But it returns another path that would be checked if it contains point in in the superview. I could use your method but I think creating two paths is simpler for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where `containsPoint:` always returned `NO`

I ended up making my own method which checks if the `CGPoint` is within the `bounds` of the `UIBezierPath`

```
- (BOOL)bezierPath:(UIBezierPath*)bezierPath containsPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGRect bezierRect = bezierPath.bounds;

    if( bezierRect.origin.x < point.x && bezierRect.origin.x + bezierRect.size.width > point.x &&
       bezierRect.origin.y < point.y && bezierRect.origin.y + bezierRect.size.height > point.y ){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Side note: you could also make this into a category method, I had no need for that.

Comment: You could also use CGRectContainsPoint rather than writing out that if statement