# UIBelzierpath - path.contains(userTouchPoint) can only detect if userTouchPoint.y is exactly at path Y position

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

[image]

I have a path like this (red middle line), which is created from

```
   func drawALine(point1:CGPoint,point2:CGPoint)->CAShapeLayer{
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: point1)
        path.addLine(to: point2)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        return shapeLayer
    }
```

Because I have multiple Lines so I have to detect which one I'm touching with this

```
for each in RulerModelArray{
            if (!(each.midPath.path?.contains(touchPoint))!) {
                print("not contain")
            } else {
                print("contained",each.ID)
            }
        }
```

Problem is if my `point1`/`point2` y is 450, and my touchPoint.y is 450.00001 then it won't be detected. There is only like 1% that I can't tap on the perfect spot.

Tested with this:

```
let testPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: touchPoint.x, y: touchPoint.y + 0.0001 )
        for each in RulerModelArray{
            if (!(each.midPath.contains(testPoint))) {
                print("not contain")
            } else {
                print("contained",each.ID)
            }
        }
///always return not contain
```

Is there anyway that I can detect the path within `shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is more universal way

works for any kinds of **straight line**,

by calculating the distance from touch point to the destination line

```
extension CGPoint{
    
    // tolerance, should by the lineWidth of a UIBezierPath

    func contained(byStraightLine start: CGPoint,to end: CGPoint, tolerance width: CGFloat) -> Bool{

        return distance(fromLine: start, to: end) <= width * 0.5
    }
    
    
    
    func distance(fromLine start: CGPoint,to end: CGPoint) -> CGFloat{
        
        let a = end.y - start.y
        let b = start.x - end.x
        
        let c = (start.y - end.y) * start.x + ( end.x - start.x ) * start.y
        return abs(a * x + b * y + c)/sqrt(a*a + b*b)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

check if the CGPoint is within the bounds of the UIBezierPath

works for horizontal line, because horizontal line's size's height is 0

```
extension UIBezierPath{
    
    func hasForHorizontalLine(pt point: CGPoint) -> Bool{
        
        let bezierRect = bounds
        let origin = bezierRect.origin
        let size = bezierRect.size

        if origin.x <= point.x , origin.x + size.width >= point.x, origin.y - lineWidth * 0.5 <= point.y , origin.y + lineWidth * 0.5 >= point.y{
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `each.midPath.path?` is a CGPath and it seems like I can't use `bounds` with CGPath. While my `midPath` is a CAShapeLayer, which always return 0 with everything to me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787971/uibezierpath-containspoint-dont-work-correctlyupdated-touch-location-in-sup